# Plot hurricane track

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, matplotlib

Hello folks, 
            Recently while going through a research paper I happened to come across a plot showing the hurricane track(figure attached). Can anyone say how it is plotted or anyone has any experience of plotting such figures? Also, I want to know what are such types of plots called.

[image].

Comment: In Python, you can do a similiar plot with `Basemap` package ([docs](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/)). Have a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62283369/9214357) on how to implement it:

Answer (score 1):

The information for this plots is provided by a meteorological service in a [Geospatial Format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeospatialFormats.html).  A common format for weather data is [ESRI shape file format (SHP)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/SHP.html). I gave a presentation on an introduction to modelling hurricane losses a couple of years ago ([YouTube](https://youtu.be/TKpaiXz_law)). There is a link to the code [here](https://files.wolframcdn.com/pub/www.wolfram.com/technology-conference/2018/Friday/Robinson2018WindstormIBNREstimate2.zip).  An example example storm track with intensity bands that was produced is:

> [image]

Hope this helps.